# Can any one tell me how can show same view of .docx file in the textarea using php

Tags: php

I want to show same view in a textarea as like .docx file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [DocVert](http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/index.html) or [LiveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/)